# Use two columns from pandas dataframe as row names and column names and fill the table with a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm not sure what's the best way to describe the problem. But an example should be helpful.

Assume this is my `pandas` dataframe

```
col1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E']
col2 = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c']
col3 = [143, 62, 12, 75, 9, 71, 40, 95, 23, 13]

df = pd.DataFrame([col1,col2,col3]).transpose()
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df

  col1  col2  col3
0   A   a   143
1   A   c   62
2   B   d   12
3   B   e   75
4   C   b   9
5   C   c   71
6   D   d   40
7   D   e   95
8   E   a   23
9   E   c   13
```

and I would like to use unique values in `col1` as my new df's row names, and unique values from `col2` as columns names, then fill `col3` values in the new df and fill in the blank with 0. For example, `newdf.loc['A','a']` will return `143`, and `newdf.loc['C','a']` will be `0`. The `newdf` should be a `5x5` dataframe.

The easiest way is to do a double `for` loop, but I'm curious if there's an easier way to do it.

I hope my explanation makes sense, and thank you guys for helping!

Comment: Sounds like you want a `pivot`.  Try `df.pivot(*df)`

Comment: @user3483203 that's exactly what I wanted, please answer the question so I can accept the answer, thanks!